# Find Highest Salary of employs in each department in SQL

Tags: sql

[image]

Result Should be the under lined rows in below image
[image]

Comment: what you tried ?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: What's the expected result if there are two persons in a department with the same max salary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use correlated subquery

```
select * from tablename t1 where salary = 
(select max(salary) from tablename t2 where t1.deptname=t2.deptname)
```

Comment: This should be using `=`, not `in`.

Answer (score 1):

use window function if support your dbms

```
select * from 
(
select *, row_number() over(partition by department order sal desc) rn
from your_tab
) t where t.rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select sal.empid,sal.name,t.department,t.sal from salary ,(select department,MAX(sal) as sal from salary group by dep)t
where  sal.dep=t.dep and sal.sal=t.sal
```

Comment: Please explain more about your problem